# Moving image in a circular path purely using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, css-animations

How can I make the imageObject to move in a circular path? Or more specific, what are the mathematical formulas needed to make it do so?

I am required to use setInterval with a function that caluclates the new coordinates of the picture. setInterval is supposed to call the function at least 20 times a second.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Graphics and animation using HTML5 Canvas</title>
        <style>
            #the-canvas { border: 1px dashed gray }   
        </style>
        <script>
            addEventListener('load', function() {
                var x = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
                var y = x.getContext("2d"); 

                var imageObject = new Image();

                imageObject.onload = function() {
                    y.drawImage(imageObject, 100, 200);
                };

                imageObject.src = "image.jpg";

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="the-canvas" width="500" height="400">   
            Your browser does not support the &lt;canvas&gt; element.
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematical formulas needed would be **cosine** in one dimension and **sine** in the other.

Something like this:

```
        addEventListener('load', function() {
            var x = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
            var y = x.getContext("2d"); 

            var imageObject = new Image();

            var step = 0, radius = 50, speed = 0.05;

            function spin() {
                y.clearRect(0, 0, x.width, x.height);
                y.drawImage(imageObject, 100 + radius * Math.cos(speed * step), 200 + radius * Math.sin(speed * step));
                ++step;
            }

            imageObject.onload = function() {
                y.drawImage(imageObject, 100, 200);
                setInterval(spin, 50); // 20 fps
            };

            imageObject.src = "image.jpg";

        });
```